# HTTP status 403.14 when trying to access website from host machine, but works inside Docker container

Tags: asp.net-mvc, docker, iis, http-status-code-403

I have an ASP.NET MVC website running in a Docker container. I verified it works by running this PowerShell command inside the container:

```
Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $url -UseBasicParsing
```

I get a 200 response and the contents of the page, so it's fine.

However, when I try to access the website from the host machine in Chrome, I get "403 - Forbidden: Access is denied." and "You do not have permission to view this directory or page using the credentials that you supplied."

In the IIS log I see the substatus code is 14, so it's a 403.14.

What are some potential causes of this problem?

Comment: Because of Docker networking, your request from Chrome can be routed to a different site on IIS (in Docker). Spend some time digging into that. 403.14 simply indicates that ASP.NET MVC routing cannot resolve the Chrome request to a valid controller.

Comment: Thank you for this. I don't know much about Docker networking, so I will definitely do some digging into that.

Answer (score 0):

Go to Properties Application and change the Windows Authentication to Enabled. I hope it will help you out.

[image: Properties]

Comment: According to Microsoft documentation: "Using Windows authentication makes sense when you are building an internal company website (an intranet site) and you want your users to be able to use their standard Windows user names and passwords when accessing the website." This is not what I want to do. It's not an intranet site.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this by first using port 8080 instead of 80 and then adding a new binding. On port 80 there was already a "Default Web Site". I added the new binding inside my container using PowerShell:

```
New-WebBinding -Name mysite -IPAddress "*" -Port 8080
```